# Binary form of a number

Tags: binary-operations

I'm a little confused about the following example given by my textbook on have to convert $\frac{2}{3}$ to its binary form

> To determine the binary representation we write
>
> $\frac{2}{3}=(0.a_1a_2a_3...)_2$
>
> We multiply by 2 to obtain
>
> $\frac{4}{3}=(a_1.a_2a_3...)_2$
>
> Therefore we get $a_1=1$ by taking the integer part of both sides. Subtracting 1 from both sides, we have
>
> $\frac{1}{3}=(0.a_2a_3a_4...)_2$
>
> Repeating the previous steps , we eventually arrive at
>
> $\frac{2}{3}=(0.1010....)_2$

Now I get why $a_1=1$ by why does $a_2=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$\frac{1}{3}=(0.a_2a_3a_4...)_2$$
we multiply by $2$ to obtain
$$\frac23=(a_2.a_3a_4\ldots)_2$$

Since $2/3<0$, $a_2$ is $0$.

Comment: You mean $2/3<1$, presumably.